# Django - When Click on Anchor View Loads but URL Does not Change

Tags: python, django

I just started learning django and just written my first view and url code.
My view code is like below:

```
def HelloWorld(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello There World!")
```

And my url line is defined as below in urls.py

```
url(r'^hello/$', HelloWorld),
```

On the index page I have an anchor as below

```
<a href="/hello">go to hello page</a>.
```

So when I click the anchor on the index page I can see the view content displayed but the url is not changed to "homepageurl.com/hello". Do you know why the displayed url is not changing?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean not changing from the previous page? Which is?

Comment: I have just tried: it works perfectly to me. I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am developing on c9.io. The default homepage url is something like https://django-python-USERNAME.c9.io/ and it is not changing to https://django-python-USERNAME.c9.io/hello/.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Apparently this problem is seen in the default "Browser" selection in cloud9. So for anyone seeing the same thing in c9.io I recommend you to open the page in one of your installed browsers on your PC and check the behaviour again or just change your browser selection in c9.io.

I checked the behaviour by opening my project URL on my Google Chrome. When I click the link, on Chrome it loads the view and the url is changed as expected but when I click the same link on cloud9's default "Browser" I can't see the same behaviour.

Seems cloud9's default browser is acting weird.
@Pynchia thanks for the comment. Upvoted.